# How to update vector's element array and its value while traversing on it

Tags: java, arrays, collections, vector

I have an array vector

**Format** like this

```
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]] , [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]], etc...
```

**Example:**

```
[['admin'],['FD'],['PRS_12121200019'],['0103AR0040N'],['Supplier'],['ST01'],
  ['null'],['ST01'],['PRS_DOOROUTERLH'],['PRS_DOOROUTERLH2']],
[['admin'],['FD'],['PRS_12121200019'],['0103AR0040N'],['Supplier'],['ST01'],
  ['null'],['ST01'],['PRS_DOOROUTERLH'],['PRS_DOOROUTERLH17']],
```

we can able to set, remove, repositioning index of a vector but how to update one value while traversing on vector.

Example: if i want to update instead of **Supplier** into **Inhouse** which is the better way

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "traversing on a vector"? Can you give an example of what you tried?

Comment: This really needs to be cleaned up and clarified.

Answer (score 1):

For replacing a value in vector you can use `set(int i,String s)`.it can replace the old value of `vector.elementAt(i)` with `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code replacing all **Supplier** string into **Inhouse** in the Vector object.

**Sample Code:**

```
    Vector<String[]> vector = new Vector<String[]>();
    vector.add( new String[] { "Supplier" } );
    vector.add( new String[] { "123" , "456" } );
    vector.add( new String[] { "123" , "456" } );

    for( String[] array : vector ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            if( "Supplier".equals( array[i] ) ) {
                array[i] = "Inhouse";
            }
        }
    }
```